# diskarbitration is 'Preventing Sleep' how to safely quit this process?

Tags: disk-utility, sleep-wake, external-disk

I used quit in Activity Monitor on diskarbitrationd process and it wouldn't quit. I then used force quit and my external hard drive was corrupted.  How do I sleep my computer when diskarbitrationd process is preventing sleep?[image]

Comment: You could try unmounting any external/networks disks.

Comment: is unmounting a safe way to eject hardware, I've had a lot of problems recently with corrupted drives

Comment: It's the only safe way.